# Duplicate question of...

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was trying to ask a question here and this happened:

[image]

---

Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like an auto-trigger to help stop the flooding of duplicate questions where the only thing different is a single term or word.

It may be better and cleaner to group the tag requests into one since they're all about merging the singular phrase into the plural.

Comment: Not always. Besides, I think it's easier to follow their status if they are separated.

Comment: @alex I think it's generally better to group your tag requests into one post, or present them as answers to a question